How to efficiently share data between methods of different classes?
Lets say there is class A, encapsulating class B, C, and D.
Class B has a callback function B::callback() that generates data which ought to be further processed by C::foo() and finally D::foo().
class A{
   public:
      void f(){
         B.run();
         //C.run();
         //D.run();
      }

   private:
      B b;
      C c;
      D d;
};

class B{
   public:
      void run(){
        set_process(callback,void* arg);  // external_lib::set_process
      }
      void callback(){
         data = get_data();
      }

   private:
      float *data;
};

class C{
   public:
      void foo(float *data){
          // process data
      }
};

class D{
   public:
      void foo(float *data){
          // final process data
      }
};

My question is:
How data flow should be designed so as to share data between B, C and D?
My current solution is a naive one:
Having defined a non-member static function void helper(), which is called within B::callback(), I am able to call C::foo() and D::foo() using pointers to member functions as follows:
void helper(float* data,void* args){
    static_cast<C*>(args)->foo(data);
    static_cast<D*>(args)->foo(data);
}

class A{
//...
};

void B::callback(){
    data = get_data();
    void *args = nullptr;
    helper(data,args);
}

.. however since I am developing a real-time app, I am looking for a solution towards optimization. And the problem with this approach is that, when casting, copies of both B and C are created, thus, I was wondering whether making helper() a member function of A (A::helper()) and passing it to B using a function pointer, I could at least cast references of c and d, nevertheless that complicates things even more.

Edit 1
I kindly thank you for your comments.
Just for the records, the solution that worked for me is to create a member function in A::share_data that passes data to C::foo and D::foo, and pass it to B by creating a setter that makes use of std::function and std::bind. In this way, B is able to call a member function of A that shares data to the rest of the member objects.
Thank you @Peter
For the sake of comprehensiveness , I am sharing a minimal example. Let me know what you think.
class A{
   public:
      void f(){
         b.set_caller(std::bind(&A::share_data,this,std::placeholders _1));
         B.run();
         //C.run();
         //D.run();
      }
      
      void share_data(float *data){
         c.foo(data);
         d.foo(data);
      {
   private:
      B b;
      C c;
      D d;
};

class B{
   public:
      void run(){
        set_process(callback,void* arg);  // external_lib::set_process
      }
      void callback(){
         data = get_data();
         _share_data(data);
      }

      void set_caller(std::function<void(float*)> A_member_f){
          _share_data=A_member_f;
      }
   private:
      float *data;
      void _share_data(float*);
};

Let me know what you think.

And the problem with this approach is that, when casting, copies of both B and C are created why do you think that? casting does not create any copies

IMHO, the most efficient method is to allow the other classes friend privilege, then the other classes can access the data members directly.

You are performing micro-optimizations.  Profile your program to see where the most time is spent in your program.  You'll get the best improvements by optimizing those sections.

@IłyaBursov Because helper is not a member function of A, but a simple function. So it does create a temporary copy of B and C. Right?

@cestpasmoi no, no copies are created

If you define getters and setters inline in the class, most compilers will generate register load instructions at higher optimizations, which is about as efficient as you can get.

helper() is wrong because it casts nullptr to C* and D*, then invokes ->foo() on each. This cannot be your real code unless foo() does not use any members of the classes.

Using void* and static_cast in a C++ program? Are you sure this is what you want? Spoiler alert probably not ;) There are only a few exceptions where this should be used... interaction with legacy API's and "type erasure" scenarios. Remember correctness (and typesafety) come before any "efficiency" considerations. maintainability and correctness have a (development) efficiency all of their own.

You say you are developing a realtime app. Have you compiled with ALL optimizations on AND profiled your code? If not do this! The steps to optimization are 1. Good design. 2. Measure. 3. Analyze bottlenecks (branche prediction and cache misses are more likely to cause issues then your actual manual "optimizations). 4. Measure again... and again.

Also you really should watch this What has my compiler done for me latety. and Explore your code on compiler explorer. You can then see what assembly your code is being compiled into

This is really unclear. Does C::foo take a parameter or not? Your code are contradictory in this aspect. Also if you are really using something as written, why can't C::foo be static? Right now nullptr dereference is UB. The question cannot be answered without first clarifying these.

Your design seems error prone to me, since you're trying to move data between objects directly between objects that are only related by the fact they are all members of an A, and then introducing all sorts of additional bookkeeping to make that happen (both performance hit and all sorts of unnecessary challenges getting that working).   I'd consider returning something (either an object or a reference to one) from b to the caller (presumably, in your scenario, a member function of A) which can pass the data as needed to other members.   A::run() might be a candidate for doing that.

I would question whether an OOP design is even appropriate here…if C and D are just meant to hold functionality to process data, could they just be top level functions operating on some shared state structure?
